# Storing timeseries of large raw requests and responses in Cassandra

Tags: python, dictionary, cassandra

I have a number of python processes that each repetitively query a separate betting API. The requests come in bursts of ~20-100 all at once, then the process goes away to parse the responses and repeats a second later or so. I am hoping to use Cassandra as my raw storage for requests and responses. This will allow me to debug problems with the parsed data and/or re-parse later. I am trying to devise a schema for this.

I am thinking I can have a separate table (column family) per API, not much to say about that. My initial idea for the table schema was:

```
stripe text, // free text to describe the flavour of the request, e.g. live games  
date int, // YYYYMMDD  
requests map<datetime, text>,  
responses map<datetime, text>
```

I could then append the requests and responses to the correct row as they happened and end up with a row per day of timewise sorted requests and responses. I could then easily go back and find data for a given day (which seems like a reasonable chunk to process at a time), then go to a specific point in time on the day if required.

The problem here is obvious, 2 requests made at exactly the same time given my timestamping resolution, will end up overwriting one another. As unlikely as it might be it is wrong.

I then went on to a second idea I didn't really like, disambiguate the key using the timestamp and a hash of the request, assuming that the same request at the same time should return the same result and therefore be unique enough, ie str(timestamp) + str(hash(request)), meaning the schema becomes (datetime becomes text)

```
stripe text, // free text to describe the flavour of the request, e.g. live games  
date int, // YYYYMMDD  
requests map<text, text>,  
responses map<text, text>
```

This sucks because text takes more space and is slower to compare but I was willing to accept it, then I hit this problem:

```
E               InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Map value is too long. Map values are limited to 65535 bytes but 435145 bytes value provided"
```

This is basically telling me I can't ever put these things in a collection column anyway as responses are of arbitrary size and almost always bigger than the limit.

I am new in the Cassandra world but thought that these CQL maps end up corresponding to separate column names and values in the record, and that each column has a size limit of 2GB. One thing I can think of is to not use a map and keep altering the table schema every time, then inserting a normal value into the cell but I am not sure how that is different in the underlying store.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

- Is this just a limitation of CQL or all of Cassandra?
- Can someone more experienced think of an overall better approach?

Thanks for reading

KCH

Comment: I suspect the answer might live in http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - my misunderstanding lies in the fact that in CQL, the first part of the key is always the row key so for a composite key the rest of the parts of the key form the column key. Maps also end up in separate columns of the same row using their own key name "unrolling" convention but applying the limit size.